# Puppet read output of command and store in a variable

Tags: linux, puppet

I am very new to puppet and trying to execute my puppet script but its failing all the time.

I want to store the output of below bash command and want to store in a variable which I can use later:

```
/usr/bin/head -1 /tmp/testfile.out | cut -d',' -f2'3
```

Which I am passing to my puppet script to read a file from another location

```
variable => generate('/usr/bin/head -1 /tmp/testfile.out | cut -d',' -f2'),
command => "/bin/cp /${variable}/application/myscript.sh /var/tmp/myscript.sh",
creates => "/var/tmp/myscript.sh",
```

But when I execute this puppet script it fails. I am not sure even if above one is correct too. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

**EDITED**

testfile.out contains a cron data which is generated using my custom php script in that I have application name on the first line of the file. Sample entry of the file :

```
cat testfile.out
server.amazon.com,zimbra,1080,3000
```

I have a script which sits on a nfs share which starts with the application name $variable and I need to copy on that server which will run check for all zimbra related files and folders. Even I am not sure about this script what it does exactly as its a binary file..

Comment: First of all you have syntax errors. You need to escape the "'"s before and after the comma.

Comment: @FlorinAsavoaie: Which line you are referring too.. If I do not use variable part in that puppet script it works so I am not sure what you are referring too.

Comment: The single quotes at `cut -d ','` need to be escaped.

Comment: Try replacing the $variable with actual syntax

Comment: You can probably work around this by deploying a shell script which executes this command. But: can you please explain better what you are trying to do? You know that `generate` runs on the master server, not the node, right?

Comment: **@faker** Yes I am learning about **generate..** thanks, what is the best way to use variable in puppet as I will be using this script across multiple servers and those will be client nodes so generate will fail. I am editing my question as you have requested. **@PratapSingh**: That does not help either ..

Comment: Add facts, that is extend facter.

Comment: I am not sure how to use facts but checking it . Thanks @Zoredache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
command => "/bin/cp \"`/usr/bin/head -1 /tmp/testfile.out | cut -d\",\" -f2`\"/application/myscript.sh /var/tmp/myscript.sh",
creates => "/var/tmp/myscript.sh"
```

It works for me ..